# Merge of two strings in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, string, plsql

Is there any way to merge two strings returned in a query like this: I have one string 
`'<6 spaces>XYZ'` and other string `'<3 spaces>ABC<3 spaces>'`. Basically each string is divided in 3 parts and two of any parts will be blank. I want to merge these two strings to produce the output: `'<3 spaces> ABCXYZ'`.

Another example can be `'ABC<6 spaces>'` and string `'<6 spaces>DEF'`  should produce `'ABC<3 spaces>DEF>'`

Comment: So, you have two strings you'd like to combine into a string that is nine characters long.  But what about when the two you want to combine have values in the same positions?  And how do you know which string comes first without having to test the value within them?

Comment: There will not be any data in a part if the other string has data in same part. Also as said only one part will have value and 2 other parts will be blank.

Comment: OK, to guaranteed to be no values in the same position.  But you haven't said if there's anyway to know which of the two strings has characters at the first or second position without checking the value itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that spaces are alphabetically earlier than letters and numbers:

```
with q as (select '   ABC   ' as c1,'      DEF' as c2 from dual
 union all select 'ABC      ', '      DEF' from dual
 union all select '   DEF   ', 'ABC      ' from dual
 union all select '      DEF', '   ABC   ' from dual
 union all select 'ABC      ', '   DEF   ' from dual
 union all select '      DEF', 'ABC      ' from dual
)
select c1, c2,
       GREATEST(SUBSTR(c1, 1, 3), SUBSTR(c2, 1, 3)) ||
       GREATEST(SUBSTR(c1, 4, 3), SUBSTR(c2, 4, 3)) ||
       GREATEST(SUBSTR(c1, 7, 3), SUBSTR(c2, 7, 3)) mrg
from q;


C1        C2        MRG       
--------- --------- --------- 
   ABC          DEF    ABCDEF 
ABC             DEF ABC   DEF 
   DEF    ABC       ABCDEF    
      DEF    ABC       ABCDEF 
ABC          DEF    ABCDEF    
      DEF ABC       ABC   DEF 

6 rows selected
```

Comment: I already voted, but wish I could again--nice use of `GREATEST`

Answer (score 4):

### Oracle 10g+:

```
SELECT t.column1,
       t.column2,
       CASE
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(t.column1, '^\w{3}') AND REGEXP_LIKE(t.column2, '\w{3}$') THEN 
           TRIM(t.column1) || '   ' || TRIM(t.column2)            
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(t.column1, '^\w{3}') AND REGEXP_LIKE(t.column2, '\s{3}\w{3}') THEN 
           TRIM(t.column1) || TRIM(LEADING FROM t.column2) 
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(t.column1, '\s{3}\w{3}') AND REGEXP_LIKE(t.column2, '\w{3}$') THEN 
           TRIM(TRAILING FROM t.column1) || TRIM(t.column2) 
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(t.column2, '^\w{3}') AND REGEXP_LIKE(t.column1, '\w{3}$') THEN 
           TRIM(t.column2) || '   ' || TRIM(t.column1)            
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(t.column2, '^\w{3}') AND REGEXP_LIKE(t.column1, '\s{3}\w{3}') THEN 
           TRIM(t.column2) || TRIM(LEADING FROM t.column1) 
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(t.column2, '\s{3}\w{3}') AND REGEXP_LIKE(t.column1, '\w{3}$') THEN 
           TRIM(TRAILING FROM t.column2) || TRIM(t.column1)   
       END AS col
  FROM table1 t
```

Supporting scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE "EXAMPLE"."TABLE1" (
  "COLUMN1" VARCHAR2(9 BYTE), 
  "COLUMN2" VARCHAR2(9 BYTE)
);

Insert into TABLE1 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) values ('   ABC   ','      DEF');
Insert into TABLE1 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) values ('ABC      ','      DEF');
Insert into TABLE1 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) values ('   DEF   ','ABC      ');
Insert into TABLE1 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) values ('      DEF','   ABC   ');
Insert into TABLE1 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) values ('ABC      ','   DEF   ');
Insert into TABLE1 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) values ('      DEF','ABC      ');
```